# How to choose from an array of sprites in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So basically I am looking to choose one of the 4 different coloured balls at random to come into the scene which each have an animation, physics properties and movement & spacing that I have already coded. I am not sure exactly how to make the array then choose at random from the array of the 4 coloured balls **so that I have one ball chosen at random to come into the scene**. 
To make it more clear what I'm asking here's some code (I only use two balls in this code so you don't have to read as much):

var moveandremove = SKAction() < this is in my ballScene.swift

*The spawn runBlock is inside didMovetoView*

let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({
            () in

```
        self.allballs()

    })

    let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)
    let SpawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
    let spawndelayforever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SpawnDelay)
    self.runAction(spawndelayforever)

    let distance = CGFloat(brnball.frame.width * 20 + brnball.frame.width)
    let moveball = SKAction.moveByX(-distance, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.003 * distance))
    let removeball = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    moveandremove = SKAction.sequence([moveball])

}


func allballs() {

    TextureAtlasblk = SKTextureAtlas(named: "blkball")

    for i in 1...TextureAtlasblk.textureNames.count{

        var Name = "blkball_\(i)"
        blkarray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
    }

    blkball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blkball_1")
    blkball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 100, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    blkball.zPosition = 7
    blkball.setScale(0.1)

    self.addChild(blkball)

    blkball.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(blkarray, timePerFrame: 0.2)))

    //brownball

    TextureAtlasbrn = SKTextureAtlas(named: "brnball")

    for i in 1...TextureAtlasbrn.textureNames.count{

        var Name = "brnball_\(i)"
        brnarray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
    }

    brnball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "brnball_1")
    brnball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 50, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    brnball.zPosition = 7
    brnball.setScale(0.1)

    self.addChild(brnball)

    brnball.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(brnarray, timePerFrame: 0.2)))
```

**Here is my terrible starting point at trying to make an array to choose from each ball (this is inside my allballs() function):**

var ballarray: NSMutableArray = [blkball, brnball, yelball, bluball]

```
    runAction(moveandremove)
```

I am new to swift and pretty hopeless, would be awesome if someone could help me out :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard for me to find the array that you're talking about in your code. But nevertheless, I can still show you how.

Let's say we have an `[Int]`:

```
let ints = [10, 50, 95, 48, 77]
```

And we want to get a randomly chosen element of that array.

As you may already know, you use the subscript operator with the index of the element to access an element in the array, e.g. `ints[2]` returns `95`. So if you give a random index to the subscript, a random item in the array will be returned!

Let's see how can we generate a random number.

The `arc4random_uniform` function returns a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and one less the parameter. Note that this function takes a `UInt32` as a parameter and the return value is of the same type. So you need to do some casting:

```
let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ints.count)))
```

With `randomNumber`, we can access a random element in the array:

```
let randomItem = ints[randomNumber]
```

Try to apply this technique to your situation.

Here's a generic method to do this as well:

```
func randomItemInArray<T> (array: [T]) -> T? {
    if array.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }

    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    return array[randomNumber]
}
```

Note that if the array passed in is empty, it returns `nil`.

Comment: This is it, you legend! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make and extension for Array that returns a random element.

```
extension Array {
  func randomElement() -> Element {
     let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - 1)))
     return self[i]
  }
}
```

You could take that a step further and allow a function to be applied directly to a random element.

```
mutating func randomElement(perform: (Element) -> Element) {
  let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - 1)))
  self[i] = perform(self[i])
}
```

You can use this function when using an array of reference types.

```
func randomElement(perform: (Element) -> ()) {
  let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - 1)))
  perform(self[i])
}
```